# Is legend in header valid ? <h1><legend> Caption </legend></h1>

Tags: html, header, accessibility, legend, markup

I would like to know if I could insert a legend inside a header. This way the legend can have also its hierarchy related to the whole document.

I have more text below which is relevant but needs to be highlighted for the readers. In this case personal information would be `legend` and `h2` at the same time. `h1` would be another element in the site which I chose not to display.

```
<fieldset>

   <h2>
     <legend>Personal information</legend>
   </h2>

   <h3>
     Credentials
   </h3>
   <label for="username">
      Username
   </label>
   <input id="username" type="text">
  <label for="surname">
      Surname
  </label>
  <input id="surname" type="text">

  <h3>
     Contact details
   </h3>
   <label for="street">
      Street
   </label>
   <input id="street" type="text">
  <label for="house-number">
      House number
  </label>
  <input id="house-number" type="number">

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend

> Permitted parent elements: A `<fieldset>` whose **first child** is this `<legend>` element

In your example the `<legend>` element is not the **first child** of its ancestor `<fieldset>`, so it is not valid HTML5 markup.

Furthermore note that also reverting the order of the elements like so

```
<legend><h2>Personal information</h2></legend>
```

the markup would not be still valid, since `<legend>` allows [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) only

Answer (score 0):

Element `legend` is not allowed as child of element `h1`.
Only as a child of a `fieldset`.

Quote from W3C validator -

> Contexts in which element legend may be used:
>   As the **first child** of a **fieldset** element.

Comment: But as you can see in this example it's already inside a fieldset, is that not valid? Or does it need to be directly a child of fieldset?

Comment: I tried to validate it in W3C validator, got an error.